# Magento Zero Subtotal Checkout - Assign Pending then immediately Proccessing

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have a email delivery module that for security reasons only send out delivery emailS if the order has had the order status PENDING and currently have the status PROCESSING.

This works great for regular orders. But for free (zero) orders, i in Admin can only select that the order either should get the status PENDING or the status PROCESSING.

How can i do so that free (zero) orders first get status PENDING and then status PROCESSING?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the "New Order Status" to `Pending`.

Then you will have to manually invoice the order, which will change the status to `Processing`.

Comment: Well, this is only half the solution. Because i need the status to instantly go from Pending to Processing. How can i do that? Using a cron would be slow, as i need it to be done instantly.

Comment: You would need to create an observer for `order_place_after`

Comment: Thanks Steve. I am not that familiar with this, can you help me with the observer code and installation instructions? Of course you will get paid.

Answer (score 0):

If for zero value orders you want the order status to default to a certain order status. In the admin go to System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Zero Subtotal Checkout.

- Change to Enabled
- Change New Order Status to Processing
- Save